# Бордер сдвигает элементы вокруг, как исправить?

Tags: css

Собтвенно при наведении на элемент, его "соседи" начинают сдвигаться и искажать общую картину. Как это можно исправить ?

```css
.inv_item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.inv_item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.inv_item img {
  width: 110px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.inv_item p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-bottom-left: 10px;
  border-bottom-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить `.inv_item {  border: 1px solid transparent; }`:

```css
.inv_item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.inv_item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.inv_item img {
  width: 110px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.inv_item p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-bottom-left: 10px;
  border-bottom-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="http://www.adolph-numerical.co.uk/images/100x100.gif" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

А зачем вы так делаете?, задайте элементам по умолчанию border: 1px solid transparent а по ховеру передавайте border-color: white. либо сделалйте это через свойство :hover {box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black}, у вас нет бордера а по ховеру выего задаете и элементы становяться больше на один пиксель, box-sizing там не поможет.

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях можно просто использовать [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/outline), который не влияет на геометрию

```css
.inv_item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.inv_item:hover {
  outline: 1px solid #888;
}
.inv_item img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.inv_item p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8);
  border-bottom-left: 10px;
  border-bottom-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIj48cG9seWdvbiBwb2ludHM9IjUwLDUgMjAsOTcgOTUsMzkgNSwzOSA4MCw5NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bGltZTtzdHJva2U6cHVycGxlO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo1O2ZpbGwtcnVsZTpub256ZXJvOyIvPjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIj48cG9seWdvbiBwb2ludHM9IjUwLDUgMjAsOTcgOTUsMzkgNSwzOSA4MCw5NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bGltZTtzdHJva2U6cHVycGxlO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo1O2ZpbGwtcnVsZTpub256ZXJvOyIvPjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIj48cG9seWdvbiBwb2ludHM9IjUwLDUgMjAsOTcgOTUsMzkgNSwzOSA4MCw5NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bGltZTtzdHJva2U6cHVycGxlO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo1O2ZpbGwtcnVsZTpub256ZXJvOyIvPjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="inv_item">
  <img class="inv_img" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIj48cG9seWdvbiBwb2ludHM9IjUwLDUgMjAsOTcgOTUsMzkgNSwzOSA4MCw5NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bGltZTtzdHJva2U6cHVycGxlO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo1O2ZpbGwtcnVsZTpub256ZXJvOyIvPjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="" />
  <p class="inv_name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

так и есть все правильно при наведении добавляется бордер поэтому и скачут т.к. бордер появляется снаружи блоков, не пробовали box-sizіng: border-box;
inv_item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}